# Running dotCover as part of an MSTest build step in TeamCity

Tags: c#, testing, teamcity, dotcover

I'm currently running dotCover as a part of my MSTest build step in TeamCity. I've configured MSTest to run the assembly files matched by `**.Tests.dll`, otherwise everything else has default settings.

I have no idea how dotCover decides which files to track (I would like to know), but I'm noticing that a lot of third party libraries and the test projects themselves show up in the report - I would like to exclude this from being analyzed and reported on. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TeamCity 7 you can specify assembly filters for dotCover. For example you can exclude a referenced assembly by adding a negative filter:

```
-:TheAssembly.To.Ignore.*
```

This would exclude any assemblies where the name started with `TheAssembly.To.Ignore`

[image]